# "Error: Unknown filesystem" on all my drives on Grub rescue

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

I was trying to start my computer in Windows safe mode and ended up pressing F8 before selecting Windows in grub instead of after and now it's stuck in grub rescue. I looked up how to use it to make it work normally again, but when I try to locate the ubuntu drive they all say "error: unknown filesystem." I did the ls command to see all of my drives as well. I've also tried botting from a live USB, but it only shows a black screen.

So what does this mean? Can it be fixed? Does pressing F8 really cause this much damage?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this message is Grub, doesn't understand most file systems by default. Grub Rescue is actually really hard to use, I would advise against using it ever. I would say your best bet is to boot to a usb. The reason it isn't booting to it now is it probably is not configured to in bios (so try changing your bios settings to boot to usb first), or your usb is just being a pain, try reinstalling the os onto the live usb. Once you can get the live usb booted, follow the steps given here:
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material. Also, please clean up your formatting. Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future. **;-)**